# Pushed view controller doesn't rotate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have two subviews in my app.

At the top is a toolbar and in the bottom is a navigation controller.

In the navigation controller I have a table which every cell push to a new view controller with a youtube video. The problem is that the video doesn't rotate.

When I am in the video viewController and rotate the app, the table gets the AutoRotate event.

When I pop the view I can see that the event happened on the table and the table is in landscape.   It was just a test, so in real time the event should rotate the video to the right view.

I have found a couple of articles which say that the ViewController won't tilt when it's not the rootViewController.

How can I respond to the video event instead of the table event?

Comment: I fixed it with a view added to the tableViewController which was hidden and when I needed it, I made an animation like push